# Is try_fold the preferred way to stop an infinite iteration or are there more idiomatic alternatives?

Tags: rust, iteration

I'm looking for ways to interrupt iteration of an infinite iterator. I found that [`try_fold`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.try_fold) accomplishes my objective. However, that requires doing the awkward thing of returning an `Err` on the successful case. What I'm looking to understand is if this is an idiomatic way of doing things. The only other way I can think of doing this is using a regular [`for`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.for.html), or something like a `find` while keeping external state (which feels even weirder!). I know in clojure there's [`reduced`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reduced), but I couldn't find an equivalent for rust.

Here's a minimum viable example. The example cycles around the initial Vec, summing each item as it goes, and stops at the first sum larger than 10. I.e. it returns 12, because `1 + 5 - 3 + 1 + 5 - 3 + 1 + 5 = 12`:

```rust
fn main() {
    let seed = vec![1, 5, -3];

    let res = seed.iter().cycle().try_fold(0, |accum, value| {
        let next = accum + value;
        if next > 10 {
            Err(next)
        } else {
            Ok(next)
        }
    });
    if let Err(res) = res {
        println!("{:?}", res);
    } else {
        unreachable!();
    }
}
```

([playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=31399bd0db1937637ea2a83c60b31c7e))

The part that feels weird to me is the `if let Err(res) = res` being the positive condition and really the only way out of the cycle (hence why the other branch is unreachable).

Is there a 'better' way?

Comment: I would advice to just not do that. Better talk about your concrete problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using [itertools::fold_while](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.10.1/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.fold_while) if you don't mind using a well established external library. There might be other useful extensions if you like this style of programming.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know about itertools! `fold_while` really looks much better suited for this purpose than my weird solution with `try_fold`. Thanks!

Comment: I also acknowledge that since itertools isn't a part of the stdlib, it probably isn't 'idiomatic' and the `for` solution proposed on the other answer would be the more common way of doing this. I'll accept this answer because it taught me about a new lib, but accepting the other one would probably be as adequate.

Comment: @jgpaiva In Rust, using external crates is the norm, and I'd go as far as to say it is idiomatic to use popular crates if it makes your code cleaner.

Answer (score 9):

Simple, just iterate normally

```rust
fn main() {
    let seed = vec![1, 5, -3];
    let mut accum = 0;
    for value in seed.iter().cycle() {
        accum += value;
        if accum > 10 {
            break;
        }
    }
    println!("{:?}", accum)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `scan` and `find`:

```
fn main() {
    let seed = vec![1, 5, -3];
    let res = seed
        .iter()
        .cycle()
        .scan(0, |accum, value| {
            *accum += value;
            Some(*accum)
        })
        .find(|&x| x > 10)
        .unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", res);
}
```

This is actually slightly shorter than using `fold_while` from `itertools`, which would look like this:

```
use itertools::{FoldWhile::{Continue, Done}, Itertools};

fn main() {
    let seed = vec![1, 5, -3];
    let res = seed
        .iter()
        .cycle()
        .fold_while(0, |accum, value| {
            let next = accum + value;
            if next > 10 {
                Done(next)
            } else {
                Continue(next)
            }
        })
        .into_inner();
    println!("{:?}", res);
}
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about scan! The part about having inner state and exposing a different thing to the external iterator melts my brain a bit. But I'll definitely explore it further to understand a bit better its semantics, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As of today, there is no obvious answer to your question which is actually very surprising. Like @peter-hall suggested, `scan` is the idiomatic functional answer to the problem but Rust's `scan` [is known to be](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/68371) [ugly to use](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/scan-is-too-complicated-suggestion-for-new-iterator-methods/13456).

In my opinion `try_fold` remains the rustiest option. Here are my combined suggestions to make looped folds more satisfying *(pick one or more changes!)* :

```
let res = {
    use Result::{Err as Break, Ok as Next};
    seed.iter()
        .cycle()
        .try_fold(0, |accum, value| match accum + value {
            res if res > 10 => Break(res),
            next => Next(next),
        })
        .unwrap_err()
};
```

Using a `match` helps naming the cases better than `if`/`else` in my opinion. The `Result` types aliases also give some semantics describing the breaking indention.

If you don't want to use `unwrap_err`, someone suggested to replace it by

```
let res = iter.try_fold(...).unwrap_or_else(|res| res);
```

It's also possible to use an irrefutable pattern:

```
let (Ok(res) | Err(res)) = iter.try_fold(...);
```

If it were for my own code, I'd keep things as simple and vanilla as possible:

```
let res = seed
    .iter()
    .cycle()
    .try_fold(0, |accum, value| match accum + value {
        res if res > 10 => Err(res),
        acc => Ok(acc),
    })
    .unwrap_err();
```

Reading `.unwrap_err()` is clear enough to me because it means that the `Err` is the return type we expect. That's my best shot, cheers!

Comment: there might be a typo in the first snippet - ControlFlow enum doesn't have Break/Next variants but Continue/Break

Comment: @BinaryButterfly `Break` and `Next` are aliases for `Err` and `Ok` for the standard `Result` type in the snippet. Aliasing helps having a more semantically readable code.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say the [ControlFlow](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/enum.ControlFlow.html) enum is made for this. [There is even an example of using it with `try_fold` in the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#examples-36).

Your example would then look like this:

```rust
let seed = vec![1, 5, -3];

use ControlFlow::{Break, Continue};
seed.iter()
    .cycle()
    .try_fold(0, |accum, value| {
        let next = accum + value;
        if next > 10 {
            Break(next)
        } else {
            Continue(next)
        }
    })
    .break_value()
    .unwrap()
```

Note that as of writing this, [`break_value()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/enum.ControlFlow.html#method.break_value) is [experimental](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/75744), meaning you'd still have to match over the result or use nightly.

Answer (score 0):

It can also be implemented with **`iter::successors`**.

```
  use std::iter;

  let seed: Vec<i32> = vec![1, 5, -3];

  let mut cycle = seed.into_iter().cycle();
  let mut acc_iter = iter::successors(cycle.next(), |n| Some(n + cycle.next()?));
  let result = acc_iter.find(|&n| n > 10);
  println!("{:?}", result);


  // if it's not ok to take ownership of the `seed`,
  // you might have to explicitly copy the first value for `successors`
  //
  // let mut cycle = seed.iter().cycle();
  // let mut acc_iter = iter::successors(cycle.next().map(|n| *n), |n| Some(n + cycle.next()?));
  // let result = acc_iter.find(|&n| n > 10);
```

Another option is to use **`iter::from_fn`**:

```
  let mut cycle = seed.iter().cycle();
  let mut acc = 0;
  let mut acc_iter = iter::from_fn(|| {
      acc += cycle.next()?;
      Some(acc)
  });
  let result = acc_iter.find(|&n| n > 10);
  println!("{:?}", result);
```